# Need help getting [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] and User.isInRole("Admin") working in Asp.Net identity 1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I just don't get how these two potentially incredibly useful functions are supposed to work.

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")] //Method A
```

and

```
User.isInRole("Admin") //Method B
```

They are clearly not working right now for me. I did a few hours of research:

I read that you need to implement System.Web.Security.RoleProvider, then set it up in the web config:

```
 <roleManager defaultProvider="OdbcRoleProvider" 
  enabled="true"
  cacheRolesInCookie="true"
  cookieName=".ASPROLES"
  cookieTimeout="30"
  cookiePath="/"
  cookieRequireSSL="false"
  cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
  cookieProtection="All" >
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add
      name="OdbcRoleProvider"
      type="Samples.AspNet.Roles.OdbcRoleProvider"
      connectionStringName="OdbcServices" 
      applicationName="SampleApplication" 
      writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

This caused the RoleProvider I implemented to by constructed, but the role checking functions were certainly not calling any of the methods in there.

**I then read that Asp.NET Identity does away with the RoleProvider**, now you need to do this:

```
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  <remove name="RoleManager" />
</modules>
```

And I did that.

I have a custom UserManager that connects to my postgres backend. The problem is that whenever I use it, I need to instantiate one. It seems to me that if Functions A and B are going to work, **then the UserManager I have implemented needs to be referenced in some sort of config file so Asp.NET knows about it implicitly.** This would be just like the RoleManager in the past.

How does ASP.NET identity alter how Functions A and B check the roles from the old RoleProvider using behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

When you call the login code like this:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
            if (user != null && user.PasswordRequiresReset == false)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe); //triggers IUserRoleStore.GetRolesAsync
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
```

SignInAsync triggers GetRolesAsync from the IUserRoleStore:

```
public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(TUser user) //where TUser is an ApplicationUser
    {

        Func<object, IList<string>> getRoles = (object user2) =>
        {
            TUser user3 = (TUser)user2;
            return user3.Roles.Select(x => x.Role.Name).ToList();
        };


        return Task.Factory.StartNew(getRoles, user);

    }
```

In the above, I chose to simply generate the roles from the roles I already loaded from the db and stored in the ApplicationUser object when I created it in FindAsync.

The roles from GetRolesAsync must be loaded in the cookie somewhere where they can be accessed quickly and easily by Functions A and B.